# Using an OR condition in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, left-join, outer-join, or-condition

Here's what I have in 2 tables.

TABLE tbl_appuntamento => This table contains a list of appointments

```
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+
    | id   | data                 | slot      | id_sede |
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+
    | 1    | 2017-03-27           | 10:00:00  | 1       |
    | 2    | 2017-03-27           | 10:00:00  | 1       |
    | 3    | 2017-03-28           | 11:00:00  | 1       |
    | 4    | 2017-03-28           | 12:00:00  | 1       |
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+
```

TABLE tbl_blocco_operativo  => This table contains a list of dates or slots in which no appointment can be set

```
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
    | id   | data                 | slot      | id_sede | is_fullday |
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
    | 1    | 2017-03-27           | 10:00:00  | 1       |0           |
    | 2    | 2017-03-27           | 11:00:00  | 1       |0           |
    | 3    | 2017-03-28           | 00:00:00  | 1       |1           |
    +------+----------------------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

I have this query

```
    SELECT appuntamento.*,blocco.slot blockSlot, blocco.is_fullday blockFullday 
    FROM tbl_appuntamento appuntamento 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_argomento argomento ON argomento.id = appuntamento.id_argomento
    LEFT JOIN  tbl_blocco_operativo blocco ON blocco.data = appuntamento.data AND blocco.id_sede = appuntamento.id_sede 
        AND ((blocco.is_fullday = 0 AND blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot) 
             OR (blocco.is_fullday = 1 AND blocco.slot <> appuntamento.slot))
    WHERE appuntamento.id_sede = :locationId
    AND appuntamento.data >= :startDate
    AND appuntamento.data <= :endDate
    GROUP BY appuntamento.id
    ORDER BY appuntamento.data, appuntamento.slot
```

The goal is to insert the columns "is_fullday" and "slot" from the second table in the results, to check if there is any conflicts with the schedule, since the appointment could be booked before anyone creates a record in the table "blocco_operativo"

Now this seems to work, but I'm not really sure the "OR" condition in the second JOIN is the best solution.
Is it ok, or I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using the `OR` in this case; the join predicate already includes equality matches on `data` and `id_sede`. With suitable indexes, I wouldn't expect the kind of performance penalty  we sometimes see with OR conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace the `OR` expression with this:

```
blocco.is_fullday = (blocco.slot <> appuntamento.slot)
```

This works because the boolean expression between parenthesis will correspond to a number 0 or 1, which is exactly what you want `blocco.is_fullday` to be compared to.

In a more verbose way, this can be written as:

```
blocco.is_fullday = case blocco.slot when appuntamento.slot then 0 else 1 end
```

#### The Full Day case

In case the full day is blocked you may consider the *slot* irrelevant. In that case the condition could be reduced to:

```
(blocco.is_fullday = 1 OR blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot)
```

Since `is_fullday` acts like a boolean, you may say:

```
(blocco.is_fullday OR blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot)
```

Comment: This will work, but it seems overly "clever" to me, more appropriate for Code Golf.

Comment: The last `=` should be `<>`.

Comment: ooops my bad it actually works. I'll choose your answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty close. I think in the fullday case you don't need to check `slot` at all. The way you've written it, a fullday slot will be considered available if there's an appointment scheduled in the `00:00` slot. (Maybe this doesn't actually come up if the business isn't open at midnight.)

```
LEFT JOIN  tbl_blocco_operativo blocco ON blocco.data = appuntamento.data AND blocco.id_sede = appuntamento.id_sede 
    AND ((blocco.is_fullday = 0 AND blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot) 
         OR blocco.is_fullday = 1)
```

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, actually I already came to this after posting the question. Thank you

Comment: This will include records that have `blocco.is_fullday = 1` and `blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot`.

Comment: @trincot Why is that a problem? If it's a fullday event, the time is irrelevant.

Comment: Not saying it is a problem, but such records would be excluded in the OP's query. Depending on OP's expectations this might still be OK.

Comment: Just to understand better @trincot, could you explain better where the difference between results is? In my JSON response I don't see any differences!

Comment: To see the difference, you need to have records with `blocco.is_fullday = 1 and blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot`, otherwise there will indeed be no difference.

Comment: @trincot The OP asked if his query was correct, I think that `blocco.slot <> appuntamento.slot` in his query was a mistake. And I explained why I my answer.

Comment: Ok! Thank you so much! Theoretically it shouldn't happen, since I run some backend controls to avoid this issue when creating blocks! I hope @Barmar won't blame me if I have chosen the other answer, but I liked so much the trick, because I often do the same in Javascript (where I have more experience). Thank you both!!

Comment: No problem at all. As I mentioned in my answer, if `00:00` is never a valid time for an appointment, and the fullday slots always use this, then the test will work. In the `OR` case it's simply redundant, but it does permit trincot's trick to work.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with your remark about *slot* being irrelevant when the whole day is booked. Then the boolean logic boils down to `(blocco.is_fullday OR blocco.slot = appuntamento.slot)`

Comment: Right, 1 is TRUE, so that's right! Very very instructive